# div background-image 404 not found vuejs

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to set a div background but it is not working. if I use same relative path with img tag it works fine but if I try to do it with div it give me 404 error.

This img tag works

```
<img src="../../public/images/toyota_cross_background.png"/>
```

but div background-image give me 404 Not Found in the console

```
<div class="hero-wrap"  style="background-image: url('../../public/images/toyota_cross_background.png');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
```

I also tried to use :style  but still no luck.

```
:style="{'background-image':'url(../../public/images/toyota_cross_background.png)'}
```

is it something about VueJs that blocking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the following, the `src` attribute starts from its position in the folder, while the CSS attributes start from the public folder.

So to access the same file from an `src` attribute this path works: `../../public/images/toyota_cross_background.png`

And from the css, you need to use the following path: `/images/toyota_cross_background.png` (Directly as if you were in the public folder)